# How do I convert a timespan into years, months and days in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting the difference between 2 dates using the following syntax:

```
DATEDIFF(minute, [Dam_Date_Of_Birth], [Calf_Date_Of_Birth]) as [minutes]
```

This query gives me the following result:

```
minutes
1748160
3711420
768960
4231380
5816779
```

How can I get these values into a year, month, day format?

Comment: What do you mean by `year, month, day format` can you show one example

Comment: Do you mean x minutes as 'x years, y months and z days'?

Comment: @RhysJones, exactly.

Comment: @GarethD, I have the start and end date. Thus, is it possible to get the amount of years, months and days between the 2 dates?

Comment: @PeetvdWesthuizen, yes sorry, I re-read the question and deleted my comment. Apologies again.

Comment: Beware of leap years. For example, what is the difference between 2011-01-15 and 2012-03-15? Is it "1 year, 2 months", or "1 year, 2 months and 1 day"?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this as well

```
DECLARE @diff float = 1748160 / 24.0 / 60.0
Declare @date datetime = convert(datetime, @diff);
Select DatePart(yy, @date) - 1900 as Years, DatePart(mm, @date) - 1 Months, DatePart(dd, @diff) - 1 Days
```

or you can simply add your minutes to '1 Jan 1900' and get the same result like this:

```
Declare @date datetime = DateAdd(minute, 1748160, '1 Jan 1900');
Select DatePart(yy, @date) - 1900 as Years, DatePart(mm, @date) - 1 Months, DatePart(dd, @date) - 1 Days
```

So you can use this like:

```
DECLARE @dtStartDate date = '01 Jan 2015'
DECLARE @dtEndDate date = '11 Jan 2015'
Declare @date datetime = DateAdd(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate), '1 Jan 1900');
Select DatePart(yy, @date) - 1900 as Years, DatePart(mm, @date) - 1 Months, DatePart(dd, @date) - 1 Days
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541570/how-to-use-datediff-to-return-year-month-and-day)

```
DECLARE @nMonth INT, @nYear INT, @mm INT, @dd INT, @getdd int
DECLARE  @dtStartDate AS DATETIME, @dtEndDate AS datetime

SET @dtStartDate = '01/01/2015'
SET @dtEndDate = '02/11/2015'
SET @nYear = DATEDIFF(yy, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate)
SET @mm = DATEDIFF(mm, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate)
SET @dd = DATEDIFF(dd, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate)
SET @nMonth = ABS(DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, @nYear, @dtStartDate), @dtEndDate))
SET @getdd = ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, 
                          DATEADD(mm, 
                                  DATEDIFF(mm, 
                                           DATEADD(yy, @nYear, @dtStartDate), 
                                           @dtEndDate), 
                                  DATEADD(yy, @nYear, @dtStartDate)), 
                          @dtEndDate))

SELECT  Convert(varchar(10),@nYear) + ' year ' + 
        Convert(varchar(10),@nMonth) + ' month '  + 
        Convert(varchar(10),@getdd) + ' day(s)'
```

**Output:** `0 year 1 month 10 day(s)`

Answer (score 0):

Solve problems 366 days :

```
declare @st_date date = '2318-01-01';
declare @end_date date = '2417-12-31';
select datepart(yyyy,dateadd(year,(year(@st_date))%4+((year(@st_date)+100)%400/100)*100,cast(0 as datetime)) + datediff(day,@st_date,@end_date) ) - 
(1900+(year(@st_date))%4+(((year(@st_date)+100)%400/100)*100)) as year
,datepart(mm,dateadd(year,(year(@st_date))%4+((year(@st_date)+100)%400/100)*100,cast(0 as datetime)) + datediff(day,@st_date,@end_date) ) - 1 as month
,datepart(dd,dateadd(year,(year(@st_date))%4+((year(@st_date)+100)%400/100)*100,cast(0 as datetime)) + datediff(day,@st_date,@end_date) ) - 1 as day
```

**output** `99 year 11 month 30 day`

total month :

```
select (datepart(yyyy,dateadd(year,(year(@st_date))%4+((year(@st_date)+100)%400/100)*100,cast(0 as datetime)) + 
datediff(day,@st_date,@end_date) ) - (1900+(year(@st_date))%4+(((year(@st_date)+100)%400/100)*100))) * 12 +
datepart(mm,dateadd(year,(year(@st_date))%4+((year(@st_date)+100)%400/100)*100,cast(0 as datetime)) + 
datediff(day,@st_date,@end_date) ) - 1 as totalmonth
```

**output** `1199 totalmonth`