# Find Number Of days and Months and years between 2 Dates

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to Get Years, months and no. of days between 2 dates.
But when dates are like below, it gives wrong output (Month part of FromDate is greater than Todate).

```
declare @FromDate date='2010-10-27'
declare @Todate date='2012-03-02'

SELECT
DATEDIFF( mm, @FromDate, @ToDate) / 12 AS years
, datediff(mm,@FromDate, @ToDate)  % 12  AS months
, DATEDIFF( dd, DATEADD( mm, DATEDIFF( mm, @FromDate, @ToDate), @FromDate), @ToDate) as Days


**It Shows Output as**
Years Months  days
1      5      -25
```

It should be 4 months and 29 days. Please tell me how can I get desired Output.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use DATEDIFF to return year, month and day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541570/how-to-use-datediff-to-return-year-month-and-day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might solve the problem - but I think, the correct values would be 1 year, 4 month and 4 days!?

```
declare @start date = '2010-10-27'
declare @ende date = '2012-03-02'


SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, @start, @ende)/12 MyYears
      ,(DATEDIFF(mm, @start, @ende)%12)-1 MyMonths
      ,DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, (DATEDIFF(mm, @start, @ende)%12)-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(mm, @start, @ende)/12, @Start)), @Ende) MyDays

--Check of result
SELECT dateadd(dd, 4, dateadd(mm, 4, dateadd(yy, 1, @start))) x
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this. This gives the desired result.

```
 (@FromDate date,
    @ToDate Date  
    )



DECLARE @Years INT, @Months INT, @Days INT

 SET @Years = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate)
   IF DATEADD(YY, @Years, @FromDate) > @ToDate
    BEGIN
        SET @Years = @Years - 1
    END

SET @FromDate = DATEADD(YY, @Years, @FromDate)
SET @Months = DATEDIFF(MM, @FromDate, @ToDate)

IF DATEADD(MM, @Months, @FromDate) > @ToDate
BEGIN
    SET @Months = @Months - 1
END

SET @FromDate = DATEADD(MM, @Months, @FromDate)
SET @Days = DATEDIFF(DD, @FromDate, @ToDate)


 Select @Years as Years,@Months as Months,
             @Days as Days
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is Correct

declare @FromDate date='2010-10-27'
declare @Todate date='2012-03-02'

SELECT
DATEDIFF( yy,@FromDate,@Todate) AS YEARS,
DATEDIFF( mm,@FromDate,@Todate) AS MONTHS,
DATEDIFF( dd,@FromDate,@Todate) AS DAYS

Comment: This isn't the correct result:
YEARS MONTHS DAYS
2         17         492