# DATEDIFF (month)

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I have a problem with DateDiff (the number of months between two dates)

When i try this :

```
 SELECT
(CASE
WHEN X IS NOT NULL THEN

CONVERT(varchar(4), DATEDIFF(YEAR, Y, C)) + ' years '

ELSE
CONVERT(varchar(4), DATEDIFF(YEAR, A, GETDATE())) + ' years '+
CAST(DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,GETDATE(),b), S), GETDATE()) AS varchar(4)) +' month '+
CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, c, GETDATE()), e), GETDATE()), DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, f, GETDATE()), g)), GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)) +' day' end)  as result

FROM g INNER JOIN k ON M=U
WHERE T=XX order by Y;
```

result look like this: **2 years 342 month 2 day**

---

But Its should be something like this : 2years 3 month 2 Day for ex.

Can someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

---

**Correct answer:**

```
CONVERT(varchar(4), DATEDIFF(dd, x, GETDATE())/365) + ' år '+

CONVERT(varchar(4), DATEDIFF(MONTH, x, GETDATE()) % 12) + ' måneder '+

CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, x, GETDATE()), x), GETDATE()), 
DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, x, GETDATE()), x)), GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)) +' dag ' end) as Y,
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use DATEDIFF to return year, month and day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541570/how-to-use-datediff-to-return-year-month-and-day)

Comment: @GordonLinoff ; done i edited , if there is anything else ,please tell me :)

Comment: @Tanner, i always check everything , if i cant figure out wat i want then i ask question and tnx for your help , i saw that question before,but its not working for me .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Can you add an MCVE (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for more on MCVEs)?

Comment: @destination-data , tnx for your comment , wich part you dont understand ! tell me , i will explain to you :)

Comment: Questions like these can get complicated, which can lead to extended conversations and wasted effort.  Example; Is *Feb 29th 2016* 1 year after *Feb 28th 2015*?  Or is it 1 year and 1 day.  Should the query return just the days, if less than a month?  Or should the format be: 0 years, 0 months and 1 day.  To avoid extended conversations about what you want, produce some sample data.  Include the output you would expect the sample to return.  Try to throw a few fringe cases in.  That gives us something to code against (which allows us to test the solutions before we post).

Comment: Tnx , i Will do that for next time

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some extra calculations. Take a look at this

```
declare @AsOnDate datetime
declare @mdob datetime
set @AsOnDate = GETDATE() 
set @mdob = '2014-12-22' 
Select 
"Years" = CASE 
WHEN (DATEPART( DAY , @mdob)) > (DATEPART( DAY , @AsOnDate))
and (DATEPART( Month,@mdob)) = (DATEPART(Month, @AsOnDate))
THEN ((datediff(month,@mdob,@AsOnDate)-1)/12) 
ELSE (datediff(month,@mdob,@AsOnDate)/12) 
END,
"Months" = CASE 
WHEN (DATEPART( DAY , @mdob)) > (DATEPART( DAY , @AsOnDate)) 
and (DATEPART( Month,@mdob)) = (DATEPART( Month,@AsOnDate)) 
THEN ((datediff(month,@mdob,@AsOnDate)-1)% 12) 
ELSE (datediff(month,@mdob,@AsOnDate)% 12) 
END
```

**Solution taken from here:**
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Dialogs/PostDetails.aspx?PostID=1423756

Comment: This is going to be more complicated if you want to implement days as well, but for the years and months it is accurate

Comment: tnx for your help , could you please give a ex for Day also !

Comment: In the same link there is a function implementation that calculates the days also (not re-tested). Check here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1042865/how-to-get-date-difference-in-years-month-and-date#bm1057924

Comment: Checked but nothing find.

Comment: @RyaN you mean that you run the function and returns wrong results?

Comment: Nup, the code you posted, just included year and month wat about day ?! i need also day to run the code.

Comment: @RyaN check the url above...in post #1057924 there is a function that calculates days also

Comment: dudde ,it was long code , days is same sql as month and year But, the calculations the two last line should be changed for days ,and i dont know exactly its should be *30)-1) or .. wat ! thats my problem for now

Comment: Hmm..i'll give it a shot again when i'll have more time and let you know

Comment: You dont have to But if you want .. is up to you. i find out , where was problem is in my query :) anyway tnx for your help and time