# Employee Total Experience SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with employees work experience. I want to get summary experience in format like yy mm dd.

```
e_id    work_from   work_to
2       2003-10-13  2004-02-12 
2       2004-02-16  2004-06-30 
2       2004-07-01  2006-01-31 
2       2006-02-01  2017-07-12
```

Result should be: 13Y 8M 27D

Query like:

```
sum(datediff(month,work_from,work_to))/12,
sum(datediff(month,work_from,work_to)%12
```

works fine, but what about days?

Comment: Something seems a bit off to me here. What about weekends, holidays, vacations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use DATEDIFF to return year, month and day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541570/how-to-use-datediff-to-return-year-month-and-day)

Comment: Is this inclusive? Does work_to on line 2 and work_from on line 3 being 1 day apart mean that 0 days were missed?

Answer (score 0):

Please note, the following query is a general summation which does not include leap years and the months are averaged between 365/12 in days since the amount of days in each month vary.  If you want an exact figure that includes the exact amount of days, the algorithm will be more involved, but hopefully this gets you in a reasonably close ballpark figure.

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), sum(datediff(year,work_from,work_to))-1) + 'Y' AS Years,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FLOOR((sum(datediff(day, work_from,work_to)) - ((sum(datediff(year,work_from,work_to)) - 1) * 365)) / 30.4166)) + 'M' AS Months,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CEILING(sum(datediff(day, work_from,work_to)) - ((sum(datediff(year,work_from,work_to)) - 1) * 365) - (FLOOR((sum(datediff(day, work_from,work_to)) - ((sum(datediff(year,work_from,work_to)) - 1) * 365)) / 30.4166) * 30.4166))) + 'D' AS Days,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), sum(datediff(day,work_from,work_to))) AS Total_Days
```

Comment: This returns a result of 13Y, 8M, 1D. 1D is incorrect, although so is the OP of 27 days.

Comment: I just edited the query above.  I think it is correct now.  I'm only calculating from one row of dates for testing and not several, so hopefully when you have your summation from your table it will work.  I included the total days which helped me check the work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. This is the closest I can get. The problem that I had is that I cant escape the M after month.

```
DECLARE @SumExp Datetime = (SELECT CONCAT(
DATENAME(day, (SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(day, WorkFrom, WorkTo))
    FROM EmployeeWorkExperience)),
DATENAME(month, (SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(day, WorkFrom, WorkTo))
    FROM EmployeeWorkExperience)),
DATENAME(year, (SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(day, WorkFrom, WorkTo))
    FROM EmployeeWorkExperience))))
SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT(@SumExp, 'yyY MM@ ddD'), '@', 'M')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE  @work TABLE(
WorkId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY ,
work_from DATETIME NOT NULL,
work_to DATETIME NOT NULL   )


    INSERT INTO @work
        ( work_from, work_to )
    VALUES  ( '10/13/2003',
          '2/12/2004'
          ),
          (
          '2/16/2004',
          '6/30/2004'
          ),
          ('7/1/2004',
          '1/31/2006'
          ),
          ('2/1/2006',
          '7/12/2017'
          )

DECLARE @seconds int

SELECT @seconds =  SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, work_from, work_to))
FROM @work 
DECLARE @VARDT DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND, @seconds, 0)


SELECT CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @VARDT) - 1900 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' year(s) ' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, @VARDT) - 1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' month(s) '
+ CAST(DATEPART(DD, @VARDT) - 1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' day(s) ' + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, @VARDT) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' hour(s) '
+ CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, @VARDT) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' minute(s) ' + CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, @VARDT) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' second(s)'
```